# Custom tag elements in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm wanting to add a custom tag element to all elements on my site but how can it be setup so Google Tag manager sees them?

**`data-tag="example"`**

e.g.

```
<a href="example.html" data-tag="menuItem">Example</a>
```

This would then be used to create a standard Universal Analytics tag that would record all elements containing `data-tag="example"`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "add a custom tag element to all my elements". Looks like you added a data attribute, `data-tag`. Did you want to use the value of that attribute in your tags as a, for example, custom dimension?

Comment: Hi @nyuen. Apologies, I got the terminology not quite right. Yes, that's exactly what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 2):

If the element you want to grab is not directly related to an element you are interacting if, then you could create a `DOM` variable and use the CSS Selector selection method. For example, if your HTML was something like:

```
<body .....>
   <header data-my-attribute="spaghetti" ...>
```

[image]

Use the CSS selector to pinpoint exactly which element you are targeting, and just pluck out the attribute value.

If you are trying to fetch an attribute of a clicked element, then you could use an Auto-Event Variable which, when interacted with, will automagically grab the value of the specified attribute.

[image]